# Magento 1.9 UK Mail Shipping Issue (Weight Vs Destination)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, shipping, multishipping

I am working on a Magento project and stuck at a point, I have to create a shipping based on weight based like ***up to 10 KG £ 5 and over 10 KG add £ 2 per KG***. I have found an extension i.e **Owebia Shipping** which is working fine. But the web store owner is using **UK MAIL SHIPPING** for product delivery and UK MAIL charge shipping amount as shown in the image below :

[image]

Now the problem is they charge different price for different zone according to the Post Codes lies between respective zone. Magento does not have such location by default.

Can anyone help me to sort out this or how do I achieve this functionality in magento?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked Table rate Shipping method. That can be used in this type of situations

Comment: Thank you @ArunKarnawat, I have checked WebShopApps MatrixRate but unable to achieve **up to 10 KG £ 5 and over 10 KG add £ 2 per KG** such functionality